# How can I access an array using an objects name value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to access several arrays by passing a parameter to a function that is basically controls a slideshow. The parameter I pass to the function is the `name`of a `<a href=#" name="rebounding" onclick="nextPlayer(this.name)"></a>`. Here is one of the arrays I am trying to access. 
`var reboundingImgs = ['tyson_chandler.png', 'dwight_howard.png', 'zach_randolph.png', 'omer_asik.png', 'nikola_vucevic.png', 'joakim_noah.png'];`

### The problem

When I pass the parameter to the function that changes the image and I use the `[index]`instead of getting the index in the array called `reboundingImgs[]`I get the letter in the `string parameter`. e.g. `parameter + "Imgs"[index]` would be "b" if index was 2 and the parameter I pass in is "rebounding". I need to access the arrays using the parameter I pass in to show the right image from the right array( I have several arrays containing images e.g. scoringImgs[], reboundingImgs[], assistsImgs[], etc)

### Here is my code

```
function nextPlayer(typeStatStr) {
    var numImgs = 6;
    var img = document.getElementById("slideImage");
    var imageName = img.name.split("_"); 
    var index = imageName[1];
    if (index == numImgs -1) {
        return;
    } 
    else {
        index++;
    }
    img.src = "..\\nbaart\\" + typeStatStr + "Imgs"[index];
    img.name = "image_" + index;
}

function prevPlayer(typeStatStr) {
    var img = document.getElementById("slideImage");
    var imageName = img.name.split("_");
    var index = imageName[1];
    if (index == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
            index--;
    }
    img.src = "..\\nbaart\\" + typeStatStr + "Imgs"[index];
    img.name = "image_" + index;
}
```

Comment: Wait a moment. Are those arrays in separate files ?!

Comment: They are global. I load them in the `<head>` I do it like this so the browser can pre load them into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an object which has properties that you can access given the name of the arrays:

```
var imgs = {};

imgs.rebounding = ['tyson_chandler.png', 'dwight_howard.png', 
                   'zach_randolph.png', 'omer_asik.png', 
                   'nikola_vucevic.png', 'joakim_noah.png'];

alert(imgs["rebounding"][0]); // tyson_chandler.png
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this approach. It's more object-oriented right? Together with you and Juans answer my slideshow is working.

Comment: I don't think object-oriented is the right word, it's more maintainable as you will end up using less code.

Comment: Saves you writing specific stuff for each `name`. This method is much more object-oriented than Juan Mellado's however, attaching data to `window` that could easily be in its own variable is bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't pass the proper array as a parameter to the function?

```
nextPlayer(reboundingImgs);
```

And then just:

```
typeStatStr[index];
```

Anyway, if the arrays are some sort of global variables (window scope?) then you can do this:

```
window[typeStatStr + "Imgs"][index];
```

Comment: I didn't think about sending the proper array (i am pretty new to programming). After I did that I figured out that I had to make 2 new functions though. The new functions find out which of the arrays to send to `nextPlayer()` and `prevPlayer()` respectively. I also tested your second suggestion `window[typeStatStr + "Imgs"[index];` and it worked good, but since it only works with global variables I decided to not use it.

Answer (score 2):

String is just type character array so by doing: `"Imgs"[index];` you are accessing the index-th element of the array of "Imgs". For instance `"Imgs"[2] == 'g'`.

If you want to access the index-th element of the array `Imgs` then you should do:

```
Imgs[index]; //Without the quotes
```

Comment: This is indeed the problem. @JuanMellado's answer shows you you can get the array variable instead of the string. Although making an imgs object as Tyriar suggests is nicer IMO.

Comment: Actually im trying to concatenate `typeStatStr`, which is a string, with another string `"Imgs"` so that it forms the name of an array and then access that array with `[index]`.